# Docker - Running Postgres Scripts inside Container

Tags: docker

I have created a docker container for postgres  using following link .Have few pre existing postgres scripts which i need to run it inside the container .

Docker Image link-
      https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/postgres/

Tried with following command still no luck

```
  ADD runsqlscripts.sh /root/runsqlscripts.sh
  CMD ["postgres" "/root/runsqlscripts.sh" ]
```

Comment: What does "still no luck" mean? You need to post your full Dockerfile, runsqlscripts.sh, what you expect to happen and what actually happens, including any error messages.

Answer (score 1):

See a previous answer of mine for the best way to do this.

["correct" way to manage database schemas in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28700859/correct-way-to-manage-database-schemas-in-docker)

The problem is that you can't run scripts immediately with the Dockerfile because Postgres won't be running when the commands are issued.

They recommend you run scripts from the `docker-entrypoint.sh` script, which will look at the `./docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` directory for scripts that should be run *after* Postgres has started.

Answer (score 0):

```
WORKDIR /workspace
CMD ["postgres", "/root/runsqlscripts.sh" ]

docker run -v /root:/workspace IMAGE_ID
```

If you want to map a host directory to your container in a given path, you need to call `-v /host:/container` in your container creation. Dockerfile can map directory but to a random path like `/dev/disk/by-uuid/af414ad8-9936-46cd-b074-528854656fcd`.

Comment: I am using  the offficial Postgres Image from the following link  :
     https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/postgres/

Following command are used to Build the Continaer . I want to map my the Script Folder of my docker host to the script_new folder of docker container and run the sql scripts on my container.
docker run --name some-postgres -e                                POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d postgres

docker run -it --link postgress_container:postgres --rm postgress_img2 sh -c 'exec psql -h "$POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR" -p "$POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT" -U postgres'

Comment: Your grammar is wrong. There supposed to be a comma between "postgres" and "/root/runsqlscripts.sh".

Comment: I am able to create the container from the above commands and postgresql is working fine . I just want to map folders of my file system to the docker file system and run sql scripts on container.

Comment: The following command maps my file system but creates a new container .

       docker run -d -name postgress_container -v /scripts/:/scripts                                        postgreimage

Comment: provide an explanation to the answer given